# 3yr old y410p runs super slow all the time

Tags: lenovo-laptop

- Windows 8.1 64-bit
- Intel Core i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz,
- 8.0GB RAM,
- Intel HD Graphics 4600 / NVIDIA Geforce 750M GT

Computer has been slow recently. This includes startup programs, opening files, installing programs, booting, shutting down, and gaming. However, CPU, RAM, and DISK usage is fairly low all the time. I confirmed this through task manager when opening programs. System restores seems to be the only way to solve AND worsen the problem. I have system restored several times and sometimes it would be back to speed, but slow down later. Sometimes it would get worse after system restoring.

I have tried the following that didn't help:

- Scanned entire system using Malwarebytes, got rid of some malwares, but they weren't the main issue.
- Scanned entire system for viruses using Avast, no viruses detected.
- Defragged and cleared up some fragmented files. It didn't fix the slowness though.
- Updated all drivers to latest version.
- Clean boot (disabled all startups/services)
- CCleaner with registry cleaning
- Ran chkdsk and sfc /scannow, found one error, but was it was unable to fix it.

Comment: What OS are you using??

Answer (score 2):

There are (at least) a couple of possible problems here -

1. Your hard drive is failing (Google S.M.A.R.T and get a program to check
   those values) to see if this is the case.  It could be that your drive
   is not reading a lot, but it is reading slowly.  Of-course, if this is 
   the case, and you have an actual hard drive light, it will be going 
   ballistic.   (* My money would be on a failing drive)
2. It could be your system is overheating and throttling down to prevent
   damage.   Have a look if the CPU fan is clogged with gunk and clean it.